# Can't insert values to MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL [fidde](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cefd0).

I create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `hydrants log` (
  `TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `TRIG` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `VALUE` int(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this view:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED VIEW `hydrants_log_maxtime` 
AS select `hydrants log`.`ID` AS `id`,`hydrants log`.`TRIG` AS `trig`,`hydrants log`.`VALUE` AS `value`,max(`hydrants log`.`TIME`) AS `time` from `hydrants log` group by `hydrants log`.`ID`;
```

After the schema created in fiddle above I try to insert this rows in **hydrants log** table:

```
insert into `hydrants log` values ('2016-05-23 10:24:17',5,7,8);
insert into `hydrants log` values ('2016-05-23 10:24:17',6,7,8);
insert into `hydrants log` values ('2016-05-23 10:24:17',7,7,8);
insert into `hydrants log` values ('2016-05-23 10:24:17',8,7,8);
```

But when I try to insert rows above I get the following error:

[image]

It seems I am doing something wrong.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in this insert statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't necessarily doing something wrong, I too encountered this bug while trying to do standard SQL operations/queries.

Any way, this is not a question for here, you should contact them like shown on the error, and hear what they have to say about it.

P.S. - Your query looks fine, shouldn't throw an error.